# Remember jQuery slideToggle on different pages

Tags: jquery, cookies, menu, slidetoggle

I have a menu with a submenu, when you click on the menu name the submenu opens, now what I want is for the browser to remember which menu is open and which one is not.

This is one of the menu's

```
<div id="block">
<div class="flip1"><img src="/test/images/arrow_right.png"><div class="f1">Menu title</div></div>
<hr />
<div class="panel1">
<a href="">submenu title</a><br />
<a href="">submenu title</a>
</div></div>
```

and my jQuery code so far

```
$(document).ready(function(){
//check if the menu should be open or not and open/hide it
var shouldShow = jQuery.cookie('show_desc') == 'yep';
if( shouldShow ) {jQuery('.panel1').show();}
else {jQuery('.panel1').hide();}

//toggle submenu on click and make a cookie to remember if it should open or hide the menu
$(".f1").click(function(){
$(".panel1").slideToggle("fast");
    if( shouldShow ) {jQuery.cookie('show_desc', 'nope');}
else {jQuery.cookie('show_desc', 'yep'); }
});

});
```

I was pretty confident this was going to work but it turns out it doesnt the submenu is opened when the page loads and it does not react on click. What am I doing wrong here? Any help is appreciated >_<

Edit:
Ok, so after some more research I changed my slideToggle function to this:
           $(".f1").click(function(){

```
        $('.panel1').slideToggle('fast',function(){
            if ($('.panel1').is(':hidden')) {
                 var state = "closed";
            } else {
                var state = "open";
            }

        });
         jQuery.cookie('show_desc', state);
    });
```

It works but only without the cookie check at the begining.

```
  var shouldShow = jQuery.cookie('show_desc') == 'open';
   if( shouldShow ) {jQuery('.panel1').show();}
   else {jQuery('.panel1').hide();}
```

And I do not understand why does this line not work... how do I check the value of the cookie so it will work D:

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're never setting the value of `shouldShow` based on the state of the page itself - only on the state of the cookie. When a menu is clicked, you need to update the cookie based on the state of the *menu*, not the value of `shouldShow` (which is never updated after the page loads).